# Using ToString of parent class without cast in c sharp

Tags: c#, string, casting, virtual

I have a base class with a long chain of inheritance. I pass around instances of a child class in a variable with the type of the base class. Can I do a ToString on the instance of the child class and have the child's ToString run (not the parents)?

Here is my attempt:

```
namespace Abc
{
    class A
    {
        string strA = "A";
        public virtual string ToString() { return strA; }
    }
    class B : A
    {
        string strB = "B";
        public virtual string ToString() { return base.ToString() + strB; }
    }
    class C : B
    {
        string strC = "C";
        public virtual string ToString() { return base.ToString() + strC; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A a = new C();
            System.Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
            System.Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This program outputs `A`. I thought that adding the `virtual` keyword would have it output `ABC`. How can I get this result without casting? Casting requires me to know the type at compile time.

Comment: it already is virtual. don't you mean override?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to declare `virtual` at each level, you only need to do that in the class that declares it, child classes should do `override` instead. Because `ToString()` is defined in `Object` which is what `A` is implicitly derived from all off your classes should just use `override`

```
class A
{
    string strA = "A";
    public override string ToString() { return strA; }

    //Added a example of somthing not declared in Object
    public virtual string Example() { return "I am in A!"; }
}
class B : A
{
    string strB = "B";
    public override string ToString() { return base.ToString() + strB; }

    //Notice the override instead of the virtual.
    public override string Example() { return "I am in B!"; }
}
class C : B
{
    string strC = "C";
    public override string ToString() { return base.ToString() + strC; }

    public override string Example() { return "I am in C!"; }
}
```

What was causing your error is you where [Shadowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392721/difference-between-shadowing-and-overriding-in-c) `ToString()`, you should have gotten a compiler warning telling you that you where doing that and you needed to use the `new` keyword to get rid of the compiler warning and explicitly state that you wanted to shadow and not override the method.