# Why hiding method not work in c#

Tags: c#

Consider this code:

```
public class A
{

    public void Method1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A.Method1");
    }
    public virtual void Method2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A.Method2");
    }
}
public class B : A
{
    public new void Method1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("b.Method1");
    }

    public override void Method2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("b.Method2");
    }
}
```

and this:

```
    B b = new B();
    b.Method1();
    b.Method2();
    Console.WriteLine("*********************");
    A a = b;
    a.Method1();
    a.Method2();
```

This is my Result:

```
b.Method1
b.Method2
A.Method1
b.Method2
```

My question is why when we call a.Method1() I get A.Method1 instead of getting b.Method1.And why method hiding not work.

**Note This line:a = b**

Comment: From [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691135(v=vs.71).aspx): *A declaration of a new member hides an inherited member only within the scope of the new member*.

Comment: Hiding you expected is known as **shadowing**. Many Q/A's are around, you can check [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392721/difference-between-shadowing-and-overriding-in-c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is why when we call `a.Method1()` I get `A.Method1` instead of getting `b.Method1`. And why method hiding not work.

Because we call a regular, non-virtual method of class `A`. The `new` modifier does not change the behavior, it just suppresses the warning:

> '...' hides inherited member '...'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

See [Knowing When to Use Override and New Keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The thing on the `new` keyword is that it works only if you create a reference of your derived type, namely `B`. But as you refer a reference of `B` to an object of type `A` the default-implementation is used instead.
Having said this the following also works for your code:

```
A a = b;
((B)a).Method1();
```

Which leads to `B.Method1` to be called.

However as `Method2` within type `A` is `virtual`, the actual override `B.Method2` is called.