# Why base class = new derived class cannot call derived class method?

Tags: c#, inheritance, clr

We have two classes A and B, B Derives from A,
I created of `A a = new B();`
Why in my code when I call method of B that does not contain A I get error.
Does it mean that Type Object Pointer is of type A? and second why When I call `SomeMethod` it calls method of A not B?

In the heap in this situation when created object instance, type object pointer points to A or B?

```
class A
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        Console.Write("This is A");
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        Console.Write("This is B");
    }

    public void OtherMethod()
    {
        Console.Write("This is New method");
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new B();

        a.SomeMethod(); // This is A method
        a.OtherMethod(); // I get error here that a does not contain definition for this method

    }
}
```

Comment: Read @TheGeneral's answer.  Basically, when you create `SomeMethod` both in the base-class and in the sub-class, you have a choice.  If you want them to be related, create the base-class version as `virtual` and the sub-class version as `override`.  If you want to have the sub-class version _replace_ the base class version (when called via a sub-class reference), use the `new` keyword.  Consider if you have a base class called `Cowboy` and a method `Draw` (implying drawing a gun).  If your sub-class is `CowboyArtist`, and you want the `Draw` method to use a pencil, use `new`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between shadowing and overriding in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392721/difference-between-shadowing-and-overriding-in-c)

Comment: Your heap question seems a little confused. If you instantiate a variable of type X then the object on the heap is of type X. It really is that simple. _As a side issue - this is also why you should ask only one question per post - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post ._

Comment: Don't think about heaps and pointers.  Instead, draw a box 1 inch (or 1 cm) square, label it `A`.  Now draw another box 1 inch (/cm) wide, but 2 high.  Label it `B` (at the bottom).  Inside that box, flush with the top, draw another 1x1 box.  Label it `A` as well.  Your first box represents an `A` created like this `var a = new A();`.  The second box is the result of `var b = new B();`.  It contains a full `A`, but is a `B`.  If you say `var aInB = (A) b`, now you are referencing that `B` object, but you are only seeing it as an `A` (i.e., the inner box that is an `A`)

Comment: `It contains a full A` I am not sure I'd use that terminology with a new programmer. A male doesn't **contain** a person. They **are** a person. Using the language of `contains` makes it sound like there is some way to get access to the person within me. There isn't.

Comment: Can I say that A a = new B(), it is B in A?

Comment: The `a` variable is pointing at an instance of `B` (Male). But it is treating it as an instance of `A` (Person). So, if you are using shadowing (like you are in your code) then you will invoke methods defined in the `A` class.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are missing the glaring warning in the IDE

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning   CS0108  'B.SomeMethod()' hides inherited member
>   'A.SomeMethod()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

[Compiler Warning (level 2) CS0108](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0108)

> 'member1' hides inherited member 'member2'. Use the new keyword if
>   hiding was intended.
>
> A variable was declared with the same name as a variable in a base
>   class. However, the new keyword was not used. This warning informs you
>   that you should use new; the variable is declared as if new had been
>   used in the declaration.

If you want to hide it, use the `new` keyword

However, if you want to call it then use `virtual` and `override` it, or just change the method name so you are not hiding it

```
class A
{
   public virtual void SomeMethod()
   {
      Console.Write("This is A");
   }
}

class B : A
{
   public override void SomeMethod()
   {
      base.SomeMethod();
      Console.Write("This is B");
   }

   public void OtherMethod()
   {
      Console.Write("This is New method");
   }
}
```

---

[virtual (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual)

> The virtual keyword is used to modify a method, property, indexer, or
>   event declaration and allow for it to be overridden in a derived
>   class. For example, this method can be overridden by any class that
>   inherits it:

[override (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override)

> The override modifier is required to extend or modify the abstract or
>   virtual implementation of an inherited method, property, indexer, or
>   event.

[Polymorphism (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism)

---

> In the heap in this situation when created object instance, type
>   object pointer points to A or B?

You need not worry your self about what happens on the heap (these are implementation details), just what the language allows you to do.

However, A technically does not exist, there is only an instance of B, that has all the implementation of A (if you need it)

Comment: Thanks for answer, However I want to know what is going on in the heap and implementation details are also interests me. I know that each object in the heap has sync block index and type object pointer, the second one helped JIT to determine what method to call. Where I can get implementation details of this situation ?

Comment: @LearnProgramming: Read the C# and .NET specs.  I've never read the .NET one, but the C# spec is surprisingly quite readable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify that you want to override a virtual function. 
Try this:

```
class A
{
    public virtual void SomeMethod()
    {
        Console.Write("This is A");
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public override void SomeMethod()
    {
        Console.Write("This is B");
    }

    public void OtherMethod()
    {
        Console.Write("This is New method");
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that I should make the method virtual, but my question is also what Type Object Pointer pointed to A or B type?

Comment: If you instantiate a variable of type `B` then the object is of type `B`.

Answer (score 0):

To get access to OtherMethod where it's currently failing, you need to tell your `A` to act like a `B`.

Change

```
a.OtherMethod();
```

to

```
(a as B).OtherMethod();
```

Comment: when I have created A a = new B(), what is the object type pointer in the heap, it points to A or B type?

Comment: But if it is the type of B, why the OtherMethod of B is inaccessible?

Comment: Imagine `A` is a ball player and `B` is a tennis player. When you tell a `B` to "be a ball player" he'll momentarily forget he knows how to serve a tennis ball. Cast `A` as his true form, `B`, so he can serve the ball.