# Inheritance works strange with DI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, inheritance, dependency-injection

I have **interface**

```
public interface IActiveDirectoryService
{
   List<ActiveDirectoryUser> GetUsersInGroup(string group);
}
```

**class** (use interface)

```
public class ActiveDirectoryService : IActiveDirectoryService
{
   public List<ActiveDirectoryUser> GetUsersInGroup(string group){...}
}
```

**fake class** (inherit from original class, I override only some methods with **new** keyword)

```
public class ActiveDirectoryServiceFake : ActiveDirectoryService
{
   public new List<ActiveDirectoryUser> GetUsersInGroup(string group){...}
}
```

When I call fake service directly, the new method (which override/hide the original method) works.

```
var service = new ActiveDirectoryServiceFake();
var users = service.GetUsersInGroup(group);
```

but when I set this class into DI in 
**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddTransient<IActiveDirectoryService, ActiveDirectoryServiceFake>();
```

and I call `_service.GetUsersInGroup(group)`, in visual studio I can see, that I have instance of `ActiveDirectoryServiceFake` but the original `GetUsersInGroup` method is called.

Why is that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is easy.

You have shadowed the method instead of overriding it ([the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392721/difference-between-shadowing-and-overriding-in-c): the **new** keyword does not override members, **override** does).

In your case, the correct code would be like this:

```
public class ActiveDirectoryService : IActiveDirectoryService
{
   public virtual List<ActiveDirectoryUser> GetUsersInGroup(string group){...}
}

public class ActiveDirectoryServiceFake : ActiveDirectoryService
{
   public override List<ActiveDirectoryUser> GetUsersInGroup(string group){...}
}
```

Comment: Exactly. Because it does not override the interface method, the call is not redirected to that class. There is no connection with that new method and the interface method.