# C#: Why isn't the expected override result coming out?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, methods, overriding

Considering the knowledge I learned, this value should definitely be printed on a value of 20 instead of 10. But why does 10 come out? Am I misunderstanding the concept of override?

```
class Parent
{
    public int Question()
    {
        return 10;
    }
}

class Child : Parent
{
    public new int Question()
    {
        return 20;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Parent parent = new Child();
        Console.WriteLine(parent.Question());
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not overriding. You're using `new`, which explicitly *doesn't* override. Use `virtual` in `Parent`, and `override` in `Child`

Comment: You're not overriding, you're hiding, you need to use `virtual`/`override` instead of `new`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between shadowing and overriding in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392721/difference-between-shadowing-and-overriding-in-c)

Comment: using `public new int ...` **doesn't** override. If you need/ want to override the base method, make the base method `virtual int ...` and the method that overrides it `override int ...`