# How to override an inherited method from within another inherited class

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

I am wondering if possible to override a method from calling console app or a super super class? I understand I can override WriteLog at DoMath.... however consider that I would like to manage this instead at the console app.

Example:

```
public class LogThings
{
    public virtual void WriteLog(string value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is the base in LogThings " + value);
    }
}
```

The class inheriting the base. I kind of thought if I add the method again and mark it with new to implement as a virtual, then I can override this in the console app that inherits DoMath?

```
public class DoMath : LogThings
{
    public double DoAddition(double a, double b)
    {
        double result;
        result = a + b;
        WriteLog(result.ToString()); // < the operation I need to overload
        return result;
    }

    public new virtual void WriteLog(string value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("this is overriding the base in DoMath");
        base.WriteLog(value);
    }
}
```

Some console app using the doMathANdLog class library:

```
class Program : DoMath
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var m = new DoMath();
        m.DoAddition(1, 2);
      
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public override void WriteLog(string value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("this is not overriding.");
    }
}
```

Result is this when running it:

> this is overriding the base in DoMath
> This is the base in LogThings 3

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why are you claiming the method in `DoMath` is overriding the base method when it is not overriding it, and instead making a new method?  If you want to override it *actually `override` it*.

Comment: You are creating an instance of `DoMath` and not an instance of `Program`. But even if you would create an instance of Program, DoMath redefines the method WriteLog instead of overriding it.

Comment: *I kind of thought if I add the method again and mark it with new to implement as a virtual* - run that by me again?

Comment: Very confusing what you want and how you trying to achieve that... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392721/difference-between-shadowing-and-overriding-in-c is probably good read for you to [edit] question to clarify what you want to achieve and what you need to be explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a simultaneously fun and annoying problem to have! :) I believe that one of the missing links here is this:

- The [`override` modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override) is related to `virtual` or `abstract` methods; a method with an `override` modifier simply provides an alternative implementation to an existing `virtual` or `abstract` method. A `virtual` method has a default implementation, an `abstract` method has no implementation at all.
- The [`new` modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier)  however can be applied to *any* method and simply allows the reuse of a *name* that was already taken. These methods are not related to each other at all, the only similarity being that they forcibly share the same name.

The problem with `new` is that the type using a `new` method "pretends" that the original implementation never existed. The *base* class however is absolutely unaware of this - `new` severs the link in the hierarchy, and this is what's casing your problem.

Generally speaking, you do not want to use the `new` modifier.

That, and you probably wanted to use `var m = new Program();` instead - reasons being explained below.

---

Consider these two pieces of code:

```cs
LogThings a = new DoMath();
a.WriteLog("something");
```

and

```cs
LogThings a = new Program();
a.WriteLog("something");
```

At this point, the method being called is `LogThings.WriteLog()`. Even though we instantiate a `DoMath` or `Program` class that provides a `new` method, the `LogThings` part of the world doesn't "know" that. It instead believes to have a `virtual` method that doesn't happen to be overridden. As a result, this code prints:

> This is the base in LogThings something

As mentioned above: `new` severs that link.

In the next example, the method being called is indeed `DoMath.WriteLog()`, because we're now simply instantiating the `DoMath()` class and call its `LogThings` method.

```cs
DoMath b = new DoMath();
b.WriteLog("something");
```

Not surprisingly, this code prints

> this is overriding the base in DoMath
>
> This is the base in LogThings something

Note that it does not print "this is not overriding" because we did not instantiate an instance of the `Program` class. Likewise, the `base.LogThings()` call has nothing to do with "overriding", it simply changes the focus to the `LogThings` type and calls whatever implementation it knows.

This is similar to the original code you used:

```cs
var m = new DoMath();
```

Lastly, consider this version:

```cs
DoMath c = new Program();
c.WriteLog("something");
```

Here, the `Program` class actually `overrides` the `virtual void WriteLog` method of `DoMath`. Consequently, this code prints

> this is not overriding.

... which is now wrong, because it does.

---

The key to understanding this is that each class containing virtual or abstract methods has what's called a virtual function table, or vtable. This vtable is "inherited" by derived classes and allows the compiler to know which implementation of a method to call (through a so-called virtual dispatch).

You can consider an entry in the vtable to be something like a pointer to the actual implementation of a method (the one from the current class), followed by a pointer to the previous implementation.

In your example of `DoMath` and `Program`, instantiating the `DoMath` class would produce a vtable consisting of only

```
DoMath.WriteLog(string) -> null
```

whereas instantiating the `Program` class would produce an entry like this:

```
Program.WriteLog(string) -> DoMath.WriteLog(string) -> null
```

This is why `((DoMath)new Program()).WriteLog()` works - even though we look at a `DoMath` reference, the compiler looks up the vtable for the instantiated type (`Program`) and can follow the chain up to the actual implementation (`Program.WriteLog`).

Do however note the makeshift `null` in there. Because the `DoMath` class declares the `WriteLog` method as `new`, it is considered to be a - well - new method, which is unrelated to the one from `LogThings`. For `LogThings`, the vtable world still looks somewhat like this:

```
LogThings.WriteLog(string) -> null
```

Because there is no legit `override` - just a *different* method that happens to have the same name - `((LogThings)new Program()).WriteLog()` calls `LogThings.WriteLog()`, as that's the last implementation in the chain. The `new` essentially "forces in" *another* vtable, resulting in this somewhat split-brained setup.

Please note that this description of a vtable is drastically oversimplified; there's plenty of good material out there on that topic however.

Comment: Thank you!. This was an excellent review of the question. I think things went off on another branch with the deep dive on the 'new' keyword and my misuse of it. Still very thorough answer. Thanks for taking the time to write it out.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, `DoMath` provides a new implementation (it's in the definition there) of the `WriteLog` method. Your `Program` class then overrides that implementation.

Where it's 'failing' is here:

```
var m = new DoMath();
```

You're not creating an instance of `Program` with its overridden method, so that override is never used. Try `new Program()` instead.