# Why do I keep getting the abstract class's string? C#

Tags: c#, decorator

When I print the first beverage out it is able to get the correct description of espresso. However the second I add a the decorator, I get issues and instead of returning "The darkest of Roasts, Mocha" I get "Unknown Beverage".

This is not homework it's from Head First Design Patterns 1st edition. However written in C# instead of Java.

Any thoughts?

```
Console.WriteLine(e.getDescription() + " $" + e.cost());

Beverage d = new DarkRoast();
d = new Mocha(d);

Console.WriteLine(d.getDescription() + " $" + d.cost());

public abstract class Beverage
{
    protected string description = "Unknown Beverage";
    public string getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }
    public abstract double cost();
}
public abstract class CondimentDecorator : Beverage
{
    public Beverage beverage;
    protected abstract string getDescription();
}

public class Espresso : Beverage
{

    public Espresso() {
        description = "Espresso";
    }
    public override double cost()
    {
        return 1.99;
    }
}

public class DarkRoast : Beverage
{
    public DarkRoast()
    {
        description = "The Darkest of Roasts";
    }
    public override double cost()
    {
        return .99;
    }
}

public class Mocha : CondimentDecorator
{
    public Mocha(Beverage beverage)
    {
        this.beverage = beverage;
    }
    public override double cost()
    {
        return beverage.cost() + .20;
    }

    protected override string getDescription()
    {
        return (beverage.getDescription() + ", Mocha");
    }
}
```

Comment: Read up on the virtual and override keywords in c#. You need to apply them to the GetDesctiption method in your Beverage and inherited classes.

Comment: @NineBerry OP showed knowledge of `virtual`/`override` - they need to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392721/difference-between-shadowing-and-overriding-in-c... (or maybe C# vs. Java if they expected C# to behave like Java with `virtual` as default). Indeed compiler complained about it with [CS0108](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0108) error...

Comment: In short: `CondimentDecorator` doesn't set a value for the base base class's (`Beverage`) `description` property, and `override string getDescription()` is overriding `CondimentDecorator`'s `getDescription`, but `d.getDescription();` is using `Beverage`'s `getDescription()` method. See Alexei's link on shadowing to understand why.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov. So. If I'm understanding this correctly. The reason why beverage's description came up instead of Dark Roast +Mocha was because I was accidently shadowing correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading on the CS108 issue and this post: [Difference between shadowing and overriding in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392721/difference-between-shadowing-and-overriding-in-c)

I did see that it was my access modifiers giving me issues. When I ended up changing my `getDescription` function to `public virtual string getDescription()`

so that my `CondimentDecorator` was able to override it with `public override abstract string getDescription();`

Answer (score 3):

`Beverage.getDescription()` is declared as `public`

`CondimentDecorator.getDescription()` is declared as `protected abstract`

You now have 2 separate methods, one public, one protected, on `CondimentDecorator`

`Mocha` overrides the latter, as you havent declared the former as `virtual` to make it overridable.

In your outer code, you call the `public` (former) one, which has not been overriden.

You're compiler should also be warning you about the fact you have declared `getDescription` twice on `CondimentDecorator`, complaining about the fact there are two methods with the same signature on it.

What you likely want instead:

```
public interface IBeverage
{
    string Description { get; };

    double Cost { get; };
}

public abstract class BeverageDecorator : IBeverage
{
    // This can be public if you need to expose it for some reason
    // But typically it's fine to have components of your decorators as internal and unexposed
    protected IBeverage Component { get; }
    public BeverageDecorator (IBeverage component)
    {
        Component = component;
    }

    public string Description => $"{Component.Description}, {DescriptionInternal}"

    protected abstract string DescriptionInternal { get;}

    public double Cost => Component.Cost + AddedCost;

    protected abstract double AddedCost { get;}
}

public class Espresso : IBeverage
{
    public string Description => "Espresso";

    public double Cost => 1.99;
}

public class Mocha : BeverageDecorator
{
    protected override string DescriptionInternal => "Mocha";

    protected override double AddedCost => 0.25;
}

var espresso = new Espresso();
var espressoMocha = new Mocha(espresso);

Console.WriteLine($"{espresso.Description}: {espresso.Cost}");
Console.WriteLine($"{espressoMocha.Description}: {espressoMocha.Cost}");
```

Should produce the following output:

```
Espresso: 1.99
Espresso, Mocha: 2.24
```